# Simplifying under square root

Tags: calculus

[image]

Can somoene explain to me how the bottom parts are equal and how they did it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{9}y^{-2/3}} = \sqrt{\frac{9y^{2/3}}{9y^{2/3}}+\frac{4}{9y^{2/3}}} = \sqrt{\frac{9y^{2/3}+4}{9y^{2/3}}} = \frac{\sqrt{9y^{2/3}+4}}{\sqrt{9y^{2/3}}} = \frac{\sqrt{9y^{2/3}+4}}{3y^{1/3}} = \frac{y^{-1/3}}{3} \sqrt{9y^{2/3}+4}
$$

Comment: When you take the square root of 9y^2/3 in the denominator, what are the steps to get 3y^1/3? I've forgotten how taking a square root of exponents works.

Comment: Just note that $9 = 3^2$ and $y^{2/3} = (y^{1/3})^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

$$1 + \frac{4}{9}y^{-2/3} = \frac{1}{9} (9 + 4y^{-2/3}) $$

Now when you take the square root of this, $\sqrt{1/9}$ simplifies to $1/3$ and moves outside the integral.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{9}y^{-\frac{2}{3}}} \\ = \sqrt{9y^{-\frac{2}{3}} \left( \frac{y^{\frac{2}{3}}}{9}+4 \right)} \\ =3y^{-\frac{1}{3}}\sqrt{\frac{y^{\frac{2}{3}}}{9}+4}$$